# MVC 3 unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

in my MVC 3 project, the following code throws an error in the FireBug - `unterminated string literal`, why ?

```
<a href='#' @(Model.SomeCondition ? "onclick='alert(\"lorem ipsum\");'":"")>click</a>
```

Comment: Why are you binding an event like this?

Comment: What is the output in the browser?